# get backgroundImage object

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

i am currently trying to get the backgroundImage object of my canvas instance and it does not work. i get what ever properties of the canvas object but not of my current loaded backgroundImage. anyone else figured out that issue? here is what i have

```
var bgImg = canvas.setBackgroundImage(img.src, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
  width: bgWidth,
  height: bgHeight,
  originX: 'left',
  originY: 'top',
  left: 0,
  top: bgTop
});
```

if i then do something like: console.log(bgImg.backgroundImage) i get null as result. for all other properties of the canvas element i get either the object return or the value if i want the width for example - so all other properties do work. what is the reason that the backgroundImage is not working?

any help is very much appreciated.

many thanks,
michael

Comment: Can we have a http://jsfiddle.net with your code ? Should be more easy to help you.

Comment: here is the fiddle. the console.log results "null"
http://jsfiddle.net/ZhNE2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because setBackgroundImage is not finished (asynchronous) when you try to display with the console.log();

html:

```
<canvas width="320" height="510" id="canvas"></canvas>
<button id="click">Click here !</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

var img = new Image()
img.src = 'http://fabricjs.com/assets/jail_cell_bars.png';

var bgImg = canvas.setBackgroundImage(img.src, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
    width: 320,
    height: 510,
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'top',
    left: 0,
    top: 0
});

document.getElementById("click").addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log(bgImg.backgroundImage);
});
```

In this example, canvas.backgroundImage is displayed in the console when you click on the button : http://jsfiddle.net/LOLKFC/PQe5e/

Comment: yes i know but i can't get the properties of my actual set background. and this is exactly what i need. i know that the other methods and vars are working. but try to get the object of the backgroundImage property set in bgImg. and the backgroundImage does exist but i can't get the object for example filtering the background

Comment: hey again,
did you tried to get the object of the backgroundImage? it is very crucial and i don't get the point why it is not working. if i want another object of the canvas instance - f.e. freeDrawingBrush it works. so why not on backgroundImage? it is very crucial for me as i want to work with filters on the background image.
many thanks in advance

Comment: thank you very much. ok it makes perfectly sense. you saved my day!

Comment: Can you validate this answer please ?!

Comment: In the top left of my answer.